# Service dosent seem to work in the background properly

Tags: android, android-service

Im making a simple stepcounter app, however the background service seems to not work properly.

In my Activity class I start my service like:

```
...
Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(service);
```

In my Service class i do:

```
...
   Notification notification = new Notification();
   startForeground(42, notification);

    db = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    eventListener = new EventListener(db);
    //register listener for sensors
    sensorManager.registerListener(eventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

In the Listener class's onSensorChangedMethod() I do:

```
...      
if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
        Log.d(TAG,new Date() + " " + event.values[0]);
        db.insertStep(new Date().getTime(), 1);
    }
```

Service config from the manifest.xml:

```
...
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"

        >
```

Even when I run in foreground the stepcounter seems to stop after a few steps. I manually test and compare with Samsung Healths step counter, which is correct with the manual steps I count while my app stops after 20-40 steps while in real it was 200 steps I walked.(I turn off the screen and remove my app from the Recent Apps and still having it in the foreground.

Have I configured the service wrong somehow? The app works when i have the app open with the screen on and in debug mode(with the screen off and app removed from recent app). However, not when I remove the USB and try it out.

I want the service to run forever and I want to leverage every step taken when the app is removed from recent app, when the screen is off etc. Any help?

Thanks.

EDIT: just read that a service intended for long running tasks should use threads inside the service. is this correct? can I see an example where this approach is used.

Comment: forgot to add, i return START_STICKY in the onStartCommand() method

Comment: so i did som testing leaving the proximity sensor on and have it vibrate when it was [CLOSE] and it seems to work any time the screen is off. Im suspecting the stepcounter sensor dosent work properly when the phone is a sleep.